# How to move a FAB in react during scrolling

Tags: css, reactjs, floating-action-button

I want to have a Fab like this

```
<Box display="flex" alignItems="center"justifyContent="center">
     <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" variant="extended" size="large" style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: '2.2rem'}}>
         <AddShoppingCartIcon />
         Add to shopping cart
     </Fab>
</Box>
```

When I enter the site, the button should be at the bottom with marginBottom: 0. When I scrole down till the end, the final position of the Fab should be e.g. marginBottom: 2rem.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using React hooks to update the style of the Fab component based on the user's scroll position. Here's an example implementation:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Box, Fab } from "@material-ui/core";
import AddShoppingCartIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart";

function ScrollableFab() {
  const [isScrolledToBottom, setIsScrolledToBottom] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      const scrolledToBottom =
        window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight;
      setIsScrolledToBottom(scrolledToBottom);
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const fabStyle = {
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: isScrolledToBottom ? "2.2rem" : "0",
  };

  return (
    <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
      <Fab
        color="primary"
        aria-label="add"
        variant="extended"
        size="large"
        style={fabStyle}
      >
        <AddShoppingCartIcon />
        Add to shopping cart
      </Fab>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ScrollableFab;
```